# VB.Net Check if a checkbox list item is checked/unchecked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox list which is filled with entries from my database on page load. I need to update an entry in my database when a item is checked and when an item is unchecked. Right now I am doing the following:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="check1" AutoPostBack="True" TextAlign="Right" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Check" runat="server">

</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And the function:

```
Sub Check(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim sql As String
    If check1.SelectedItem.Selected = True Then
        sql = "UPDATE Customer SET unauthorized = 'True' WHERE ID = @ID"
        db.execUpdateQuery(sql, New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", check1.SelectedItem.Value))
    Else
        sql = "UPDATE Customer SET unauthorized = 'False' WHERE ID = @ID"
        db.execUpdateQuery(sql, New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", check1.SelectedItem.Value))
    End If
End Sub
```

But when I uncheck a button the else case is never ran. Also, if I have 4 buttons checked and I uncheck all four buttons, when I uncheck the fourth button I get an error at the line:

```
If check1.SelectedItem.Selected = True Then
```

The error is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Is there a better way to check if a list item is checked or unchecked?

Thanks

Comment: With old school HTML unchecked checkboxes don't return values to the server...maybe that's what you're running into here? With nothing checked there would be no SelectedItem in your checkboxlist.

Comment: Shouldn't you be basing this on ItemCheck and not SelectedIndexChange?

Comment: @APrough I tried that out and it doesn't run the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < check1.Items.Count; i++)
  if (check1.GetItemChecked(i))
    // Do selected stuff
  else
    // Do unselected stuff
```

If the the check is in indeterminate state, this will still return true. You may want to replace

```
if (check1.GetItemChecked(i))
```

with

```
if (check1.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
```

if you want to only include actually checked items.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid the use of a for loop?

Comment: @ewein Why do you want to avoid a For loop?

Comment: its not very efficient to loop through each item and do a database update on each iteration.

Comment: I just need something that allows me to get the item that was checked or unchecked then I can do a single update.

Comment: So don't update on each loop, update at the end. Also, be careful with dynamic sql strings. You open yourself up to SQL Injection if not handled correctly. Since Items is a collection, you may be able to maneuver that into some LING magic and get what's checked and then update it in the Db.

Comment: Now check the modified answer. clbIncludes was the check box list.

Comment: How would I update at the end? The for loop Romil suggested is checking each list item, if it is checked do an update and set to true else do an update and set to false. I guess I could check before each update to see if it is already true or false and just do a select instead of an update.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
            sql = "UPDATE Customer SET unauthorized = 'True' WHERE ID = @ID"
            db.execUpdateQuery(sql, New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", check1.SelectedItem.Value))
        Else
            sql = "UPDATE Customer SET unauthorized = 'False' WHERE ID = @ID"
            db.execUpdateQuery(sql, New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", check1.SelectedItem.Value))  
        End If
    Next
```